# Scraping web-data, finding the appropriate selector for rvest (i think)

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the Crossfit Games Open leaderboard. I have a version that worked in previous years, but the website changed and I can't seem to update my code to get it to work with the new site.

The issue I have is I can't seem to get the correct CSS selector to get the athletes name and the link to their profile.

My old code does something similar to this:

```
library(rvest)

# old site
old_url <- "https://games.crossfit.com/scores/leaderboard.php?stage=1&sort=1&page=1&division=1&region=0&numberperpage=100&competition=0&frontpage=0&expanded=0&year=16&scaled=0&full=1&showtoggles=0&hidedropdowns=1&showathleteac=1&is_mobile=1"
old_page <- read_html(old_url)

# get the athletes profile url
athlete_link <-  html_attr(html_nodes(old_page, "td.name a"), "href")
athlete_name <-  html_text(html_nodes(old_page, "td.name a"))

head(athlete_link)
# [1] "http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/124483" "http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/2725"   "http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/199938"
# [4] "http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/173837" "http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/2476"   "http://games.crossfit.com/athlete/499296"

head(athlete_name)
# [1] "Josh Bridges"    "Noah Ohlsen"     "Jacob Heppner"   "Jonne Koski"     "Luke Schafer"    "Andrew Kuechler"

# new site
new_url <- "https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard?page=1&competition=1&year=2017&division=2&scaled=0&sort=0&fittest=1&fittest1=0&occupation=0"
new_page <- read_html(new_url)

# get the athletes profile url
# I would have thought something like this would get it.  
# It doens't seem to pull anything
html_attr(html_nodes(new_page, "td.name a.profile-link"), "href")
# character(0)

html_text(html_nodes(new_page, "td.name div.full-name"))
# character(0)
```

I've tried various other CSS Seclectors, SelectorGadget, and a few other things.  I'm experienced in R but this is the only real web scraping project I've ever done so I'm probably missing something very basic.

Which selector should I be using to grab this data?

Comment: "You may not use any data mining, robots, scraping 
or similar data gathering or extraction methods to obtain Site content [...]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the content of this page is generated dynamically with some javascript. You can inspect the source of the page and you'll see something like:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- dynamically generated content goes here -->
</div>
```

where the table should go. In these cases, rvest isn't enough.
You can check this recent blog post that has useful pointers: https://rud.is/b/2017/02/09/diving-into-dynamic-website-content-with-splashr/

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected I was going to need something like RSelenium.  I'll give splashr a try.